# Webpack with babel-loader: Using an entry point that is outside of the build project

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use webpack+babel-loader with a pattern that keeps my builder project separate from my app source project.

Essentially:

```
/builder-project/build.js
/app-project/app.js
```

In `build.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var compiler = webpack({
    entry : './../app/app.js',
    output : {
        filename : 'out.js'
    },
    bail : true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});

compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And `app.js` contains a basic ES6 module.

On running `build.js` I can't get rid of a `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory [absolute-path-on-my-machine]/app-project`. So basically it's looking for the npm modules supporting babel-loader relative to the path of my entry point, not the building script.

I've experimented with `context` and `resolve` pars in the webpack config but can't seem to webpack/babel-loader to not load its stuff relative to my entry point. To me it would make more sense to keep library paths relative to the building script, rather than the entry point, but maybe things weren't designed that way?

**UPDATE**

So the answer below from @nils definitely solved the immediate issue. However the same problem is happening again within the second included module. I didn't include the source for it above, but have a look:

`app.js`:

```
import Factory from './../../vendor/factory-project/factory.js';

var App = Factory.define({
  //...
});

export default App;
```

The `factory-project` folder is initialized with `npm` and has a `node_modules`. When I run the build, although the loader now works fine on `app.js`, it throws the same error as before when processing the `import` within it: `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory [some-path-on-my-machine]/factory-project`. It's looking like even when using `resolveLoader` as indicated in the answer, it seems to be ignored when including a file from a project folder that is initialized with `npm`.

**UPDATE 2**

There is a known bug causing this. See my answer below for the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close with the `resolve` option, there is one called [`resolveLoader`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader).

[From the documentation:](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)

> IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to. This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file. If you have loaders installed from npm and your node_modules folder is not in a parent folder of all source files, webpack cannot find the loader. You need to add the node_modules folder as absolute path to the resolveLoader.root option. (resolveLoader: { root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") })

Assuming your `node_modules` folder is in the same folder as `build.js`, you could write the following:

```
var compiler = webpack({
    entry : './../app/app.js',
    output : {
        filename : 'out.js'
    },
    bail : true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hah, ok, so your solution did help, thanks. However it's more complicated than that. Within my `app.js` I have an `import` that pulls another module within another project, `import otherModule from './../../other-project/module.js'`. Because there is a `node_modules` inside of `other-project`, I am getting the same `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory` error on that directory now. Seems `resolveLoader` is getting overridden. Any further thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Just do be clear: Does it work when you don't include the other module from the other project? Either way, assuming you are only running one instance of webpack, including a file from another project should not be the issue. Are you sure that `path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')` points to the right directory? Try `console.log`ing it.

Comment: It does work when I don't include the other module within `app.js`, so the `resolveLoader` path is correct (and technically my original question is answered). But it's odd that importing a module from an external directory that's been initialized with `npm` seems to break things again.

Comment: Updated my question above with the newest happenings

Comment: Does the issue still appear if you rename either the `node_modules` folder or the `package.json` file, or both?

Comment: Issue still appears. So perhaps it's not either of those that's actually the issue... :(

Comment: Found the issue, see my answer:

Answer (score 1):

So it would appear this is a known bug:
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/166

I'm going to accept @nils' answer because that's what *should* work, but until the bug is resolved one must use the workaround of putting a `require.resolve` in the presets:

```
var compiler = webpack({
    entry : './../app/app.js',
    output : {
        filename : 'out.js'
    },
    bail : true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015')]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')   //no work :(
    }
});
```